Serialization Error While Executing WCF Client Generated from Workday Inventory WSDL in .NET 8
I am encountering an issue while executing a WCF client generated from the Workday Inventory v43.1 WSDL. I used Visual Studio 2022 (dotnet-svcutil Version 2.1.0) with the .NET 8 framework to add the service reference and generate the client code.
WSDL URL:
https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Inventory/v43.1/Inventory.wsdl
When I execute a call to the service method Get_Inventory_BalanceInput, I get the following serialization error:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'There was an error in serializing one of the headers in message Get_Inventory_BalanceInput: 'CodeGenError(IsNotAssignableFrom): Cannot convert source type [WorkdayInventory.Inventory_Par_RemovalObjectType[]] to target type [WorkdayInventory.Inventory_Par_RemovalObjectType].'

What I have tried:

Manually adjusting the generated code: I attempted to modify the auto-generated proxy code to address the type mismatch, but fixing one issue causes cascading errors elsewhere.

Re-generating the service reference: I removed and re-added the service reference, but the problem persists.


Questions

How can I resolve the CodeGenError (IsNotAssignableFrom) serialization error when consuming this WSDL?

Are there alternative approaches to consuming this Workday WSDL in .NET 8?


Any guidance or alternative tools/methods for consuming this service would be greatly appreciated.

Somewhere in there, code is trying magically convert an array of something (WorkdayInventory.Inventory_Par_RemovalObjectType[]) to a single instance of on of those things (i.e., a WorkdayInventory.Inventory_Par_RemovalObjectType) and failing. I hope this helps you dig out the problem

Thanks for your input. I found a bunch of places and tried fixing it, but there are a of other variables impacted similarly to this. Looking for an automated way to resolve this issue or an alternative approach to avoid making manual changes.

Have you found which place had the convert error?
